# creating a process that works "without team members' realizing" makes a manager good or bad?

Tags: team-management, communication, team-building

When I started to manage a team of software developers 3 years ago; I realized that there was no development process. First of all; i created 3 groups: backend, frontend and graphic design. After a year; the process of development cycle (backend->frontend->graphic design) was working.

Last year; one of developers in our team said that: "we created a good working process in our team and this worked without plan, it just happened". After this speech; I realized that as a manager I created a process that works, but my team was thinking that; there was no plan, it just happened.

I am trying to understand that if it makes me a good or a bad manager?

Comment: The problem with this question is that it's phrased as an opinion poll. It could be reworked to be on-topic, but as written it's just a request for opinion-based validation.

Answer (score 5):

T think this actually marks you a s good leader even more than a good manager.

This has always been one of my favorite quotes:
“A leader is best when people barely know he exists, not so good when people obey and acclaim him, worse when they despise him. But of a good leader who talks little when his work is done, his aim fulfilled, they will say: We did it ourselves.” – Lao-Tzu

Sounds like your situation.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this makes you a great manager. The ability to fix the problems within the team without burdening the team with it, is something i would like to be able to do. This not only improves the work processes, it gives better morale to the team and in the end makes the managers life easier.

However, i would say that in some cases this might turn against the manager as well. The way i see it happening is if you have a team that is hostile towards you because of one reason or another. In that case implementing managerial decisions without the full knowledge of the team will be great - they cannot protest what they do not know, but it will not solve the lack of respect the team has towards you. Because if they do not understand the decisions you have made, they will keep thinking they are a great team without you and keep being hostile towards you. So maybe if i was in that position specific position, i would not go with the unseen route, but that's me not liking the hostility between the project manager and the team.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent manager. How should we judge the quality of a manager?

- Does the work get done?  Yes, and the processes improve to make the future brighter
- Are the employees happy?  Yes. They believe they are responsible.

I can see two possible risks. First if the employees have a false sense of empowerment and capability,then whemn they discover the illusion,  they will question their positive self image. You have to work with them to ensure that the team is capable of continued self improvement. Second if you reside in an organization that values style over substance, you may not be credited with the achievement, which may compromise your future career.  You may wish to work with you management to plan the next improvement.  It is difficult to not be credited if you plan and predict the outcome.

On the other hand, I am not sure this question is about project management.  Perhaps questions about supervision and careers should be moved to workplace.se?

Comment: Mark, I would argue that this IS PM related. Oftentimes PM's have to find some way to get the work done, without the requisite authority. Ndemir found a way to improve his processes, without exercising any authority (even if he had it). A great skill in a PM. The fact that he wasn't sure if it was a good or bad thing marks it as a pm topic.